# Programmatically rearrange blocks in region and save in database?

Tags: 7, blocks, cron, theming

Need to react on site events and regroup blocks in front.

I have my region 'Top' in front, configuration is like this:

Block2: India News

Block1: World News

Block3: Frontpage content

When new nodes added my code must place block2 higher then block1. But I need to save new configuration in database, so hook_block_info_alter() does not help.

Please, which hook allows to save in db new blocks configuration in my region using cron?

Comment: What Drupal version?

Comment: What is your goal? When there's new content for Block2, that moves to the top? And when there's new content for Block1, that moves to the top?

Comment: yes. move one to top if any new node appears in each of them.